# Can you add permissions for user using their login name instead of user ID using SP2013 REST?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In SP2013 Rest api, I want to add permissions to a user. The user is picked from the people picker control. And I can only get the key like

```
i:0#.w|ups\stom
```

I can't get the actual user ID (number format). And from the examples of adding permissions using REST, you need a user ID. So is there a way I can use the string key above instead of the numeric ID to target the user I want to add permissions to?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using JavaScript for this or something else?  If you are using Javascript I can whip you up a sample using user ID.  Are you setting permissions at the site or list or item level?

Comment: I'm looking for just js+rest but in 1 call using that user login name. I'm setting permissions at item level

Answer (score 0):

From:http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/798407/SharePoint-REST-API-Get-User-Id-by-User-Name

```
function GetUserId(userName) {
        /// change this prefix according to the environment. 
        /// In below sample, windows authentication is considered.
        var prefix = "i:0#.w|";
        /// get the site url
        var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
        /// add prefix, this needs to be changed based on scenario
        var accountName = prefix + userName;

        /// make an ajax call to get the site user
        $.ajax({
            url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='" + 
                encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                ///popup user id received from site users.
                alert("Received UserId" + data.d.Id);
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This makes an additional call to get the ID, which I was trying to avoid. I was looking for a way to set permissions using that login name instead of user ID.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the the JSOM to get the same information.

You can also get other details using JSOM easily(https://bmspblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/18/creating-a-people-picker-in-a-web-part-page-sharepoint-2013/)

```
function getUserId(loginName) {
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
context.load(this.user);
context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess), 
     Function.createDelegate(null, onFail)
    );
}


function ensureUserSuccess() {
    $('#userId').html(this.user.get_id());
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
```

Comment: This makes an additional call to get the ID, which I was trying to avoid. I was looking for a way to set permissions using that login name instead of user ID.